# Would introducing water into a piston increase or decrease pressure?

Tags: heat-engine

Suppose you were to introduce a small amount of liquid water into the cylinder of an IC engine just after combustion. The timing and amount of water would be such that the water was entirely vaporized before the piston had moved very far. The vaporization of the water would lower the temperature of the gases in the piston and that would decrease the pressure of the hot gases but at the same time it adds more gas in the form of water vapor which would increase the pressure.

Is there some equation or rule of thumb to tell which effect is greater and how much? I'm wondering how much this could decrease operating temperature with minimal loss of power.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The addition of water into the combustion chamber of an internal combustion engine is called *water injection* and was done to reduce temperatures inside the engine to the point where the pistons, etc. would not begin to soften from the high heat and blow up at high power settings.

The water also helped suppress detonation of the fuel-air mixture and encourage deflagration instead, to reduce the tendency of the engine to explode or beat itself to pieces while running at high power settings.

Much was written about the thermodynamics of water injection in piston engines of the WWII era. A search on *water injection* should reveal what you desire.

Note that in piston engines, water injection was typically used only on takeoff, where the engine must operate at its full maximum power rating- which produces the highest temperatures inside the engine.